# C can I open a directory's files using open dir in an alphabetical order?

Tags: linux

In windows when you are opening files using open dir and dirent it will give you the files in an alphabetical order but in linux it does not is there any way to get the files sorted too in linux?

Comment: No, it returns them in the order that they exist in the filesystem. If you need to sort them, collect them into an array and sort it yourself.

Comment: @Barmar, I'd say this is not only an answer, but a good one.  How about posting it?

Answer (score 5):

No, `readdir()` returns directory entries in an arbitrary order, generally the order that they exist in the filesystem. If you want them ordered by some criteria, sort them yourself.